# IntelliJ double click to not treat hyphen as word separator

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.1 with the Cursive Clojure plugin.

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to not treat hyphens (`-`) as a word separator when double-clicking?

The use case is that I want to select a hyphen separated symbol (e.g. `foo-bar`). I double click on `foo` and only `foo` is selected. I want all of `foo-bar` to be selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't at the moment. There's an issue in the tracker for this ([#55](https://github.com/cursiveclojure/cursive/issues/55)), I'll try to implement this soon.